# Convergence of Power Series to Its Cesaro Sum

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, power-series

Let $\{a_n\}_{n\geq 0}$ be sequence of real numbers, let $s_n=a_0+\dots+a_n$ be its partial sums and $\sigma_n=\dfrac{s_0+\dots+s_n}{n}$ be partial Cesaro sums. Assume $\sigma_n\rightarrow \sigma$. I want to prove if $f(x)=\sum_{n\geq 0}a_nx^n$, then $f$ is convergennt power series for $|x|<1$ and $f(x)-\sigma)=(1-x)^2\sum_{n\geq 0}(n+1)(\sigma_n-\sigma)x^n$ so $ \lim_{x\rightarrow 1^-}f(x)=\sigma$. By theorem 8.2 in baby Rudin, the result is true if $\sum_{n\geq 0}a_n$ convergs. But I still have no idea if $\sum_{n\geq 0}a_n$ does not converge.
[image]
[image]

Answer (score -1):

If $\sum_{n\geq 0}a_n$ does not converge, $\lim_{x\to1^-}f(x)$ may not exist. For example, let $a_n=\frac{1}{n+1}$ and then
$$ f(x)=\sum_{n\geq 0}a_nx^{n}=-\frac{\ln(1-x)}x,|x|<1. $$
So
$$ \lim_{x\to1^-}f(x)=\infty. $$

Comment: How do you know if the sequence is cesaro summable?

Comment: For $|x|<1$, $\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac1{n+1}x^{n}$ converges.

Comment: how does it imply the sequence is cesaro summable?

Comment: What is your meaning of cesaro summability?

Comment: As I mentioned in the post, it is assumed the sequence is cesaro summable, $\sigma_n$ is a convergent sequence

Comment: Do you suppose $\sum_{n \ge0}a_nx^b$ converges for $|x|<1$?

Comment: That's what I want to prove. I think I got the solution for that but I haven't managed to figure out tge equation for $f(x)-\sigma$.